# How to prove the index of a nilpotent matrix cannot be greater than its matrix dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_{n\times n}(F)$, it that possible that $A^{n + 1} = 0$ but $A^{n} \neq 0$?
If this is impossible, how to prove this

Comment: If $A^n=0$, then $A^{n+1}=AA^{n}=0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $A^{n}=0$ then $A^{n+1}=0$. Just multiply both sides by $A$.

Perhaps you wanted to ask if we can have $A^{n+1}=0$ but $A^{n} \neq 0$. This is not possible. All the eigen values of $A$ are $0$ so the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda ^{n}=0$ which implies $A^{n}=0$.

Comment: Ah! Yes, that is what I wanted to ask. But suppose $A^{n+1}$ = 0, how do we know all the eigenvalues of A are 0?

Comment: $Ax=ax$ implies $0=A^{n+1}x=a^{n+1}x$.

Answer (score 0):

> **Nilpotent Matrix:** A square matrix $~A=(a_{ij})_{n \times n}~$ is called nilpotent matrix of order $~k~,~~(k\le n)$ provider it satisfies the relation, $~A^k=O~$ and $~A^{k−1}≠O~$; where, $~k~$ is positive integer and $~O~$ is null matrix and $~k~$ is the order of the nilpotent matrix $~A~$.
>
> or,
>
> A square matrix whose all eigen values are zero is a nilpotent matrix.

Now for your $~n\times n~$ matrix $~A~$, $~A^n=O~$ i.e., if $~A~$ is a nilpotent matrix of order $~n~$,  then all eigen values of $~A^n~$ are zero, then obviously we get eigen values of $~A^{n+1}~$ are all zero. i.e.,   $~A^{n+1}=O~$.

i.e., there exists a nilpotent matrix $~A~$ where $~A~$ is $~n \times n~$ matrix such that $~A^{n}~$ is a zero matrix and then also $~A^{n+1}~$ is zero matrix.

Comment: I am so sorry that I made a mistake in my question, I have already fixed it.

Comment: Regarding your new edit, please notice the definition of Nilpotent Matrix, you will get your answer.